# @NotNull validation doesn't work when query params are wrapped in Java record

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, query-string

The problem is that `@NotNull` and `@NotBlank` don't work when I try to validate fields of the record. When I call my service without one of the params (they are not present in URL), I expect 400 bad request response, but I get 500 system error (NPE) because it went further in the code where I didn't expect null values.

URL of the service call:
http://localhost:8080/api/client?searchKey=NAME&value=John

Invalid URLs which should respond with 400, but in fact they don't:
http://localhost:8080/api/client?searchKey=NAME
and
http://localhost:8080/api/client?value=John

Record which aggregates query parameters:

```
@ValidPersonSearchParameter
public record PersonSearchParameters(
        @NotNull SearchKey searchKey, // enum
        @NotBlank String value
) {
}
```

@ValidPersonSearchParameter:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = PersonSearchParameterValidator.class)
public @interface ValidPersonSearchParameter {
    String message() default "Invalid search parameter";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator:

```
public class PersonSearchParameterValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPersonSearchParameter, PersonSearchParameters> {

    private ConstraintValidatorContext context;
    private PersonSearchParameters parameters;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(PersonSearchParameters parameters, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // validation logic
        // here I trust PersonSearchParameters to do validation, but it doesn't, so I get NPE
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/client", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class PersonController {

    @GetMapping
    public PersonInfoResponse getPersonInfo(@Valid @NotNull PersonSearchParameters parameters) {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fallen for the same error as you recently. Lost a day almost.
Then realized that spring does not activate validation by default anymore.
You need to add the dependency `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your pom.xml in order to make work the `@Valid` and other validation annotations.